# Configuring php.ini file in my wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver

I want to be able to submit info entered into a form in a php app running on my local machine (wamp server) to an e-mail address. What should the key configuration settings for my php.ini file be? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a mail server configured on your PC or on your network?

Comment: No I do not. Let me work on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The php `mail()` function does not actually send mail it just passes it on to a mail server, that would be what you configured in `php.ini` if you had a mail server.

Because you are running on windows and windows does not come with a mail server by default you either have to install a windows based mail server like hMailer or use a library like phpMailer which will allow you to use your yahoo/google/other email account to send mail.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much.